# CSS: select last element at specified depth (two-level menubar)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have a multi level menu: menu line + some items may have a drop list.
Items in menu line are separated by '|' and obviously the last item should not have it's border

The problem is that `last-child` here captures the very last item in the last dropdown list and I need to capture menu line item (item3).

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzRJz.png)

```css
/* MENU */

div.menu {
  display: inline;
}
div.menu a {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
div.menu a:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
/*DROP DOWN*/

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.dropdown_content a {
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="">Item1</a>
  <a href="">Item2</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">Item3</a>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
      <a href="">Subitem1</a>
      <a href="">Subitem2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need pure CSS solution, please no JS
It should work on IE11
I suspect that maybe the menu html structure is not ideal too ... so maybe some different structure would automatically solve the issue.

Thank in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `:last-child` condition to the div element. Because your last anchor is under the last div. Where `>` denotes the immediate child.

```css
/* MENU */

div.menu {
  display: inline;
}
div.menu a {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
div.menu > div:last-child > a {
  border-right: 0px;
}
/*DROP DOWN*/

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.dropdown_content a {
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="">Item1</a>
  <a href="">Item2</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">Item3</a>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
      <a href="">Subitem1</a>
      <a href="">Subitem2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like both rules should be there: for `a:last-child` and `div:last-child > a`. Because last item can be drop list or just a regular item. But then it works. Thanks for the advice ! :)